# How do I pre-populate an Ionic 2 ion-input field?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

How do I pre-populate an Ionic 2 ion-input field?

I tried doing the below but the field remained blank.

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.content" name="content" value="123" required></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as shown below.

**Working** [**Plunk is here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/akQN3m?p=preview).

**.ts**

```
  product:any= {};
  constructor(public navController: NavController) {

    this.product.content='123';

  }
```

**Note:** Don't use `any`. Always use `type` with the `TS`. I just showed simple demo here.

**.html**

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.content" name="content"  
     required></ion-input>
```